# Is there a way to simplify this TSQL Case statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

Is there a simpler way to write the case statement in the select or is this the only way?
Basically if COL B AND COL C are not NULL, THEN col b - col c, if one is null, select the other.

```
SELECT
    COL_A AS [A],
    CASE WHEN NULLIF(COL_B, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(COL_C, '') IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT(COL_B, ' - ', COL_C)
         WHEN NULLIF(COL_B, '') IS NULL AND NULLIF(COL_C, '') IS NOT NULL
             THEN COL_C
         WHEN NULLIF(COL_B, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(COL_C, '') IS NULL
             THEN COL_B
     END AS [B]
```

Comment: <pedantry> There is no `case` _statement_ that provides flow of control. There is a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ that returns a value. </pedantry>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Basically if COL B AND COL C are not NULL, THEN col b - col c, if one is null, select the other.*

Using [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', COL_B, COL_C) AS [B]
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72976f0db152aa67a8fe7c1549bc684f)**

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't know about this function. And for clarification, does it treat empty strings as NULL? Like do I need to use CONCAT_WS(' - ', NULLIF(COL_B, ''), NULLIF(COL_C, '') as B?

Comment: @PatrickS Empty string is not treated as NULL so NULLIF is a proper way to handle it if it should be skipped too.